# How can I edit my code so that I can account for output that goes against my sed command

Tags: database, bash, sed

I am writing a code to put the species named matched from a remote NCBI BLAST database, and the file the matched name came from. I want to make my code more robust so that it can deal with files that do not get a match and that go against my current sed command

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ./split.contigs.Parsed/*.csv ; do   
  sciname=$(head -1 $i | sed -E "s/([A-Z][a-z]+ [a-z]+) .+/\1/")  
  contigname=$(echo $i | sed -E "s/.fa.csv//" | sed -E
  "s/\.\/split.contigs.Parsed\///")  
 echo "$sciname,$contigname"
done
```

Expected

```
Drosophila melanogaster,contig_66:1.0-213512.0_pilon
Drosophila melanogaster,contig_67:1.0-138917.0_pilon
Drosophila sechellia,contig_67:139347.0-186625.0_pilon
Drosophila melanogaster,contig_68:3768.0-4712.0_pilon
```

Actual

```
Drosophila ananassae,contig_393:1.0-13214.0_pilon
,contig_393:13217.0-13563.0_pilon
Drosophila sp. pallidosa-like-Wau w,contig_393:14835.0-18553.0_pilon
Apteryx australis,contig_393:19541.0-21771.0_pilon
,contig_393:21780.0-22772.0_pilon
Drosophila sp. pallidosa-like-Wau w,contig_393:22776.0-31442.0_pilon
Drosophila melanogaster,contig_394:1.0-89663.0_pilon
```

Comment: Provide some sample input.  In particular, show the first lines of `contig_393:13217.0-13563.0_pilon` and other the files for which the existing code fails.  Otherwise, we are just left guessing at what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply skip the loop if `$sciname` is null. Put this one line after defining `$sciname`:

```
[[ -z $sciname ]] && continue
```